# Completely confused about extremely basic differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

I am having trouble understanding what should be extremely simple. I am comfortable with the more algebraic definition of a differential form as in Bott and Tu as the tensor product of the algebra of smooth functions on $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the anti-symmetric tensor algebra as in,
\begin{equation}
\label{algebraicdefinition}
\mathbb{C}^{\infty} \left( U \right) \otimes \bigwedge E \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $E$ has a basis $dx_{i}$. My confusion is in relating this to the definition in terms of a map from $U$ to the algebra of alternating functions. Let's specialize to the case of a $2$-form for now. I am given the definition of a differential form $\omega$ as a smooth map
$$ \omega: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \to Alt^{2}\left( \mathbb{R}^{n} \right) $$
Now in terms of $\eqref{algebraicdefinition}$, this might look like
$$ \left( x^{2} + y^{2} + 3xyz \right)dx \wedge dy  $$
for example.  So say I take the case $n=3$ and consider $\left( a, b, c \right) \in U$ and so evaluating $\omega$ there gives, say
$$ \omega_{\left(a, b, c \right)} = \left(a^{2} + b^{2} + 3abc \right)dx \wedge dy.$$
My question is, how is this an alternating function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? If took a concrete example and took two elements of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, say, $u = (1,2)$ and $v=(3,4)$, how would I actually calculate the value of $\omega_{\left(a, b, c \right)}\left( u, v \right)$?

I realize this is an extremely simple question, but I am finding the literature on differential forms very unhelpful. I'm still not entirely sure what "$dx$" actually is as a mathematical object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give: $dx\wedge dy (u,v)= dx(u)dy(v)-dx(v)dy(u)=1\cdot 4-2\times 3$. The prefactor (with a,b,c) is just a prefactor.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. So I'm guessing then that $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ applied to $u$ and $v$ would just be a sum over permutations of the $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ as linear functionals on the coordinates taking into account the sign of the permutation?

Comment: Yes, except that you should act upon 3 vectors u, v and w.

Comment: True, of course. I really appreciate your help, and as expected my question was very simple. So since I am more comfortable with the algebraic approach, is there some kind of natural interpretation of the $dx_{i}$ in terms of the tensor algebra of the dual of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ quotient by its symmetric subalgebra? Are the $dx_{i}$ simply the equivalence class of the dual of the $e_{i}$ basis element in this quotient?

Comment: If you interpret $e_i$ as the tangent vectors (see the response of Rene Schippens) then $dx_i$ is simply the dual. The wedge may be though of as a quotient (by all pair-exchanges) but I personally wouldn't use that in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer, but you said any help...So $dx$ is the dual to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.
Thus

$$dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=1$$
$$dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=0$$

Then $dx\wedge dy$ is defined as in multilinear algebra via a matrix so 
you should get

$$ dx\wedge dy (\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=1$$

$$ dy\wedge dx (\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=\begin{vmatrix}0&1\\1&0 \end{vmatrix}=-1$$